# Install Percona Data Recovery Tool for InnoDB on Ubuntu 18

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu, percona

Has anyone successfully installed the Percona Data Recovery Tool for InnoDB on Ubuntu 18? I downloaded the tool here: https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb/trunk/release-0.5/+download/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb-0.5.tar.gz

...but when I compile I get this error:
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'constraints_parser' failed
make: *** [constraints_parser] Error 1

Comment: Does it provide a list of "constraints"?  Is that editable?  If so, let's see the list.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix the issue:
sed -i 's/CFLAGS=/CFLAGS=-fgnu89-inline /' Makefile

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained why it fixed the problem.